# Firefox add-on: domain declaration

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I developed a simple javascript injection which works very well.
Can anybody tell me how to define the domain on which I want my firefox add-on to work for?

E.g. this doesn't work for www.myexample.com in main.js:

```
const self = require("self"),
page_mod = require("page-mod");

exports.main = function() {
    page_mod.PageMod({
        include: "*myexample.com*",
        contentScriptWhen: "ready",
        contentScriptFile: self.data.url("inject.js")
    });
};
```

These lines also don't work:

```
include: "*.myexample.com/*",
include: "*.myexample.com*",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.10/packages/api-utils/match-pattern.html):

```
include: "*.example.com",
```

The `match-pattern` module recognizes when you intend to match the domain name only, no need to add wildcards after the domain name.

Comment: Thanks! I looked up the documentation but there wasn't a search option. So I didn't find the page.